# SQL: time of interval within a defined interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I have an issue where I have two defined mutually exclusive periods of time:
**NIGHT** Between 18:00 and 06:00
**DAY** Between 06:00 and 18:00

I then have records with an interval of **BEGIN** and **STOP** times, I basically want to calculate what portion (i.e. how many hours/minutes) of said interval falls in the **DAY**/**NIGHT** periods.

*All of my times are integers in hhmm format so 645 means 6:45 and 1801 means 18:01

So for...

```
BEGIN  STOP  NIGHT  DAY
0      650   600    50
1951   235   644    0
930    1500  0      530
1700   2122  322    100
```

I really don't care about the time format, I just need to understand the arithmetic used to solve this problem in an efficient way that does not involve several nested conditional statements.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `case`.  Here is an example breaking out the periods into three (you can combine the first and third):

```
select (case when begin < 6
             then least(6, end) - begin
             else 0
        end) as night_1,
       (case when begin < 18 or end > 6
             then least(18, end) - greatest(begin, 6)
        end) as day,
       (case when end > 18 
             then end - greatest(begin, 18)
             else 0
        end) as night_2
```

For your actual calculation, you should define:

```
begin_hours = floor(begin / 100.0) + (begin % 100)/100.0
end_hours = floor(end / 100.0) + (end % 100)/100.0
```

Then use these values in the previous query.  This converts the values to decimal hours.

Comment: As you pointed out, I forgot to add that I am using SQL-SERVER which does not recognize LEAST/GREATEST.

Comment: @dandroid . . . You can do the same thing with a `case` expression.